# Synchronous Invocation of AWS APIGATEWAY to a Step Function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, aws-step-functions

We have created a simple step function in AWS , via **synchronous** invocation :

[image]

When I click "Start Execution", I do see that the flow is Synchronous , with the expected result:

[image]

However, When I attach this step function to a proxy APIGATEWAY via :

[image]

I do not see the expected result. I only see this :

[image]

**Question:**

How can I make the Apigateway to wait for the step function invocation (Synchronously) ?

Comment: I believe this answer might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68687896/7661119

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi can u plz post it as a short answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have a step function being invoked synchronously, you might need to use a Step Function with an Express workflow.
On the API Gateway side you need an `Integration Request` with the `Action` set to `StartSyncExecution`.

This answer goes in-depth how to set-up the integration between the API Gateway and the Express Step Function: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44041821/api-gateway-get-output-results-from-step-function/68687896#68687896)